# Two images side by side and responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put two images side by side and make them responsive. The problem now is, that the second image wraps first and then reacts to the size of the browser.
I want them to stay on the same line (level) and change their size automatically and wrap at a certain point (this part isn't the problem)....

The html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="outer">
      <div class="itemwrapper">
        <img src="item2.jpg" alt="bag" />
      </div>
      <div class="itemwrapper">
        <img src="item3.jpg" alt="pen" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 60px auto 60px auto;
  background-color: #DDD
}

.itemwrapper {
  display: inline;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: are image same size or ratio ?

Comment: Why have you taken an answer that doesn't work? This will confuse people searching for the answer to this question.

Comment: Now, it solves the problem. The comment "This evokes another problem though. The images arent filling the itemwrappers." refers to another problem which is basicly something specific that i also wanted to achieve. The both are independent.

Comment: Can you select an appropriate answer for this. This post is being looked at alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but I'm doing it with a different solution now, whicha friend suggested:

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  padding-top: 25%;
  background-color: #999;
}
    
.itemwrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
    
.item2 {
  left: 50%;
}

#outer img {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="outer">
      <div class="itemwrapper">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" alt="bag" />
      </div>
      <div class="itemwrapper item2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="pen" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This evokes another problem though. The images arent filling the itemwrappers. I think i need to write some js for this :S.

Comment: Why did you choose this specific solution rather than those provided in the answers?

Answer (score 8):

use display table to set it side by side and keep it side by side and responsive.

`display: table;` with `table-layout: fixed;` will create a fluid layout for child elements with `display: table-cell;`

this will not only keep them the same width but also keep the containers the same height.

`vertical-align: top;` will keep them aligned to the top alternatively you can change the vertical position to `middle` and `bottom` plus some others.

Any questions just fire away.

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 60px auto 60px auto;
  background-color: #DDD
}
#outer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.itemwrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="itemwrapper">
      <img src="item2.jpg" alt="bag" />
    </div>
    <div class="itemwrapper">
      <img src="item3.jpg" alt="pen" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you integrate the "make the image wrap at some point" part in this solution?

Comment: Use a media query to over size the image

Answer (score 2):

if image are same size or same ratio, you may use flex , width and min-width to set a break point:

```css
#outer {
  width:70%;/* demo*/
  margin:auto;/* demo*/
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#outer>div {flex:1;}
#outer>div>img {
  width:100%;
  min-width:200px;/* demo*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="itemwrapper">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" alt="bag" />
    </div>
    <div class="itemwrapper">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="pen" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

remove or reset to your needs the rules commented with *demo*.

Comment: Flex has very poor support especially in IE and mobile devices.

Comment: @DCdaz your comment is half a year old and I don't know if things have changed so much, but looking at http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox I'd rather say that Flex is well supported by all major browsers with the exception of IE (partially supported) and old Android browsers (Android v. 4.3 and lower). I wouldn't define that "very poor support", what's your current opinion?

Comment: @jj_ Hi Mate, yeah support is alot better now granted but its still quite poorly supported. Alot of users still on IE and the support on android is still terrible. Especially if you are using the wrapping. also although alot of browsers are claiming full support there has been loads of reports of terrible rendering and just pure madness going on. aswell as terrible hardware issues on mobile. css table is still a much safer approach. and if you need the wrap-ability use some small JS. if you are going to use flex make sure you enable hardware acceleration and give it a right good test.